# ng-repeat nested and List of KeyValuePair

Tags: c#, angularjs, asp.net-mvc, angularjs-ng-repeat, keyvaluepair

I have an object in my Model with a property defined as below

```
List<KeyValuePair<DTO_AWTR, string>> AWTR_DRAWING
```

`DTO_AWTR` is an other object so defined:

```
public partial class DTO_AWTR
{
    public string ITEM_NUMBER { get; set; }
    public string PLANT { get; set; }
    public string PLANT_EMAIL { get; set; }
}
```

In my view I want to iterate throw all elements in my list but there something wrong. I see that the number of rows but with empty fields.

```
<table>
    <tr ng-repeat="draw in dataItem.AWTR_DRAWING">
        <td ng-repeat="(key, value2) in draw"></td>
        <td>{{ key.PLANT }}</td>               
    </tr>
</table>
```

Do you suggest something about this issue?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

the structure you have mentioned here `List<KeyValuePair<DTO_AWTR, string>> AWTR_DRAWING` serializes to

```
[{key : {ITEM_NUMBER : "", PLANT : "", PLANT_EMAIL:""}, value : ""}, ...]
```

so you should use ng-repeat keeping this structure in mind.

```
<table>
    <tr ng-repeat="draw in dataItem.AWTR_DRAWING">
        <!--this will contain {key : {object structure}, value : ""} -->
        <td ng-repeat="(key, value2) in draw.key" ng-bind="key"></td>
        <!--this will contains key = "ITEM_NUMBER|PLANT|PLANT_EMAIL"-->              
    </tr>
</table>
```

**NOTE - depending upon the js serializer you might be using most probably newtonsoft json. the object keys might be camelCased

Comment: So it's better to call the object key with a camel case notation? But also the properties of DTO_AWTR?

Comment: It seems that it is the second iteration that doesn't work.
If I add a row after the first iteration I can see my object 
`<td>{{draw}}</td>`

Comment: i have edited my ans. Earlier was trying to put {{key}} on a separate td element which obsly was wrong

Answer (score 0):

try this:

```
<table>
    <tr ng-repeat="draw in dataItem.AWTR_DRAWING">
        <td>{{ draw.key.PLANT }}</td>               
    </tr>
</table>
```

Comment: I don't understand why you have 2 repeats.. you have a single list. you navigate in that list using first ng-repeat. So your draw object contains a KeyValuePair object.. you need from there the Key property (i'm not sure if the K is capital or not). The Key property contains a DTO_AWTR object.  From that object you need the PLANT property. So in my opinion should works draw.key.PLANT. What is shown if you try to display draw.Key property?